# How to make this searchable combobox accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm working on fixing this piece of code that creates this searchable combobox. I'm using a jQuery plugin called bootstrap select and I'm just trying to add some HTML elements so it can be properly read by the screen reader (using Mac VoiceOver).

I had gone thru many iterations using aria attributes, roles and others. The following code is the best iteration of it.

```html
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control input-sm uif-multiSelectControl required validChar-document.developmentProposal.ownedByUnitNumber0 advanced_select" aria-required="true">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="uk9itrp_control" title="select" role="combobox" aria-label="Lead Unit" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="filter-option pull-left">select</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 221px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 40px;">
        <div class="bootstrap-select-searchbox">
            <input id="to_fix_krad_bug" name="to_fix_krad_bug" type="text" class="input-block-level form-control valid dirty" role="combobox" aria-owns="results_jx1xgk">
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="combobox" id="results_jx1xgk" style="max-height: 169px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
            <li rel="0" class="selected hide" role="option"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">select</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
            <li rel="1" role="option" class=""><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">000001 - University</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
            <li rel="2" role="option" class="hide"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">AA-AAAA - Unit A/span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
            <li rel="3" role="option" class="hide"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">BB-BBBB - Unit B</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the combobox is focused (which focuses on the button) it's now properly reading it as a combobox and its label. Once you go on that, it doesn't appear to recognize the elements of the list. I tried adding aria-labelledby to the li elements but didn't had any luck.

I'm also using aria-owns on the input where the focus goes when you open the combobox so it get linked with the list.

I cannot move a lot this html since it's a plugin and I'm just trying to add attributes and make it accesible. Suggestions?

Comment: You've seen https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#combobox ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Spent hours going thru documentation and didn't accomplished what I wanted and thats why I came here.

Comment: Please provide a working example with all the needed code!